# Betrayal at the house on the hill movements/attacks

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If a hero walks through a room that has a monster in it does the monster get to attack or is the only penalty the reduce speed?

It seems so unlikely that a hero would be able to get in and out of the room without being swung at.

Comment: Please separate the second question into its own question; there should only be one question per post unless they are closely related.

Answer (score 6):

Monsters never automatically attack; they only attack based on the haunt-specific rules that traitor has. It’s possible for a specific haunt to have a rule such as what you are asking about, but it is a turn-based game; and normally characters only get to act on their own turn.

Since you brought up how it works thematically (it is a game based on theme after all), the -1 movement when you leave a room with a monster kind of explains it... think of it as moving extra slowly and spending time going the long way around the room in order to avoid the monster and sneak by it.